# How to delete a layer from a Grass 7 mapset? (Grass 7 plugin in QGIS 14.9)

Tags: gis, grass

I'm using the Grass 7 plugin in QGIS 2.14.9 and I can't find how delete a layer from the Grass mapset.

This function doesn't exist in the file management module.

Answer (score 1):

Try g.remove it may help. It allows deleting a set of layers by matching patterns. patterns can be wildcard or regular expressions.

Examples in the documentation of g.remove are clear enough to get started cleaning up your mapset.